# How do I make collapsed Bootstrap Navbar open to full screen height smoothly?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have Bootstraps collapsed Navbar open to the full height of devices while overlaying above the contents of the page. I found that there is a class for the Navbar called "fixed-top" that overlays above the contents of the page but I can't seem to have it open to the full height of the screen normally. Using `.collapse ul{height: 100vh;}` the Navbar opens normally up until the last Nav item then afterward 'jumps' to the bottom of the screen. How do I prevent this 'jump' and have the Navbar open to full height smoothly?

[image: Navbar 'jump' issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sudden jump is because you are adding the height to the collapse class that isn't present until the last moment of the animation. Instead try to give the height to a custom class or one that you have already applied like nav-bar.